# BeautifulSoup ничего не находит в html странице

Tags: python, парсер, bs4

Прочитывая сайт, в теге body имеется только скрипт тайп = текст джаваскрипт.

Соответственно если я пытаюсь изъять какой-либо тэг, он ничего не находит

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    prognozy = soup.select('div')
    return prognozy

def main():
    url = 'https://vprognoze.ru/'
    print(get_html(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте `selenium`:

```
# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver

URL = 'https://vprognoze.ru/'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get(URL)
    print(f'Title: {driver.title!r}')

    for a in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.title_news > a'):
        print(a.text)

except:
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Результат:

```
Фьолнир - Валюр от Football2020 | 27-07-2020
Стьярнан - Викингур Рейкьявик от Football2020 | 27-07-2020
Хаммарбю - Эребру | Беневенто - Кьево | Кротоне - Фрозиноне от Sailor1263
Арсенал - Челси | 01-08-2020 от Footbets11
Фьолнир - Валюр от Limonchello | 27-07-2020
Саннес - Улл/Киса | 27-07-2020 от Football2020
Фаллон Шэррок (Анг) - Хосе Антонио Хустисия Пералес (Исп) | 27-07-2020 от riadik2000
Стьордалс-Блинк - Стреммен | 27-07-2020 от Football2020
ФК Торонто - Нью-Йорк Сити | 27-07-2020 от Limonchello
Микульските - Маринкович от RunnerUp | 27-07-2020
Тяньцзинь Жунган - Гуанчжоу Лонг Лайонс от genii1978 | 27-07-2020
Хосе Антонио Хустисия Пералес (Исп) - Скотт Марш (Анг) | 27-07-2020 от riadik2000
Nigma - FlytoMoon от Artorias | 27-07-2020
```

Comment: большое спасибо!

а есть объяснение тому почему bs4 не справляется с этим?
мне просто так удобно и просто им пользоваться что жалко менять структуру проекта)

Comment: @Skazalasobaka, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :) Ну, он не имеет при себе javascript-движка. Вообще, пока я смотрел запросы того сайта, тот кусок javascript он перестает подсовывать при наличии cookies, но я не уверен насчет их срока, возможно он часто меняется. А так, можно было бы получить cookies и отправлять их обычным запросом `requests` и нормально парсить. Кст, похоже, тот кусок js нужен был только для обфускации запроса, что позволит получить cookies, для удобной дальнейшей работы

Comment: к сожалению, подставляя куки всё равно не обходит js(

Comment: @Skazalasobaka, возможно, они устарели, или незаполнили какие-то другие заголовки запроса
Запрос HTTP от скрипта не будет отличаться от запроса браузера, если скрипт заполнит правильно все поля. Но я бы переписал на селениуме -- по затратам/времени это, я думаю, будет меньше, чем эти разбирательства с тем сайтом :)

Comment: Эксперементировал по всякому. Да, про бс4 придётся забыть. Большое спасибо)